# How to Fetch Dynamic Id of an object and show data related to it in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

So let me give you an overview of the problem I am facing.
I am working on a project which has handpicked project as shown below on home page.[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zYek.png)

So now I want to show all the associated properties with the specific projects like this
[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xxwM.png)

I have a databse table named "properties" which has a column "project_id". I want this "project_id" to be dynamic . Right Now I am entering the project id manually i.e. 1,2,3,4.

This is the ajax I am using in  my blade file

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        getProperties();
        function getProperties() {
            $.ajax({
        url:'/handpickedproperties/{$id}',
        type:'POST',
        data:{'property_type':property_type},
        success:function(response){
            if(response.success){
                var str = '';
                stringlength = 135;
                if($( window ).width()<1363)
                    var stringlength = 100;
                $.each(response.data, function(k,v){
                    description = v.description;
                    if (description.length > stringlength)
                        description = description.substr(0,stringlength)+'.....more';
                    photos = JSON.parse(v.images);
                    if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(photos)){
                        image_count = 0;
                        cover_photo = '/images/default/photo not available.png';
                    }
                    else{
                        image_count = Object.keys(photos['withPhotos']).length;
                        cover_photo = photos.coverPhoto;
                    }
                    area_conversion = JSON.parse(v.area_conversions);
                    str += '<div class="property-box" data-aos="fade-up">\
                                <div class="pic-area">\
                                    <figure><img src="'+cover_photo+'">\
                                        <span class="photo-count">\
                                        <img src="images/photos-icon.png">'+image_count+'</span>\
                                    </figure>\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="listing-property-details">\
                                    <a href="/viewPropertyDetails/'+v.id+'">\
                                        <h5>'+v.name+' in '+v.address+'</a><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="addFavourite(`'+v.id+'`)" class="wishlist" style="margin-top:0"><img src="/images/home/heart2.png" id="pic_'+v.id+'"></a><a href="/viewPropertyDetails/'+v.id+'"></h5>\
                                        <span class="price-box">\
                                            <strong>'+v.currency+v.price+v.price_unit+'</strong>\
                                            '+v.currency+' '+v.price_per_area+'/sq.ftadsds.\
                                        </span>\
                                        <span class="area-box">\
                                            <img src="/images/listing-area.png">\
                                            <strong><span class="sq_ft" style="width:75%;display:inline-block;">'+v.area_per_sq_ft+' sq.ft.</span>\
                                            <span class="sq_mt" style="width:75%;display:none;">'+area_conversion.sq_mt+' sq.mt.</span>\
                                            <span class="sq_yrd" style="width:75%;display:none;">'+area_conversion.sq_yrd+' sq.yrd.</span></strong>\
                                            ('+v.carpet_area+') Carpet Area\
                                        </span>\
                                        <span class="bed-box">\
                                            <img src="/images/listing-bed.png">\
                                            <strong>'+v.bedroom+' BHK</strong>\
                                        </span>\
                                        <span class="bath-box">\
                                            <img src="/images/listing-bath.png">\
                                            <strong>'+v.bathroom+' Bath</strong>\
                                        </span>\
                                        <div class="clear"></div>\
                                        <p class="property-brief" style="color:black;">'+description+'</p></a>';
                    if(v.featured == 1)
                        str += '<label style="margin-right: 5px;" class="featured-highlight-buttton">Featured</label>';
                    if(v.verified == 1)
                        str += '<label style="margin-right: 5px;" class="highlight-buttton">Verified</label>';
                    if(v.construction_status == 3)                      
                        str += '<label style="margin-right: 5px;" class="highlight-buttton">Under Construction</label>';
                    if(v.construction_status == 4)
                        str += '<label style="margin-right: 5px;" class="highlight-buttton">Ready to Move</label>';
                                // <label class="highlight-buttton">Resale</label>
                    str += '</div>\
                                <div class="listing-box-bottom">\
                                    <span>\
                                        Posted on '+v.creation_date+' by '+v.created_by+'\
                                        <a href="/total-listed-properties" target="_blank"><strong>'+v.posted_by+'</strong></a>\
                                    </span>\
                                    <a href="#" onClick = "contactDetails(`'+v.id+'`);">Contact '+v.posted_by+'</a>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>';
                });
                $('#results_number').empty();
                $('#results_number').append(Object.keys(response.data).length);
                $('#property-data').append(str);
                $('#no-result-found-div').hide();
            }
            else{
                $('#property-data').empty();
                $('#results_number').empty();
                $('#results_number').append(0);
                $('#no-result-found-div').show();
            }
        }
    });
        }
     });   
</script>

enter code here
```

**This is my controller Code**

```
 public function handpickedProperties(Request $request,$id)
  
    {
        try
        {
            $data           = $request->all();
            $validator      = Validator::make($data, [
            ]);
            if ($validator->fails())
                return $this->sendError("Validation Failure",$validator->errors(),403);

            $price_min = 0;
            $price_max = 10000000;
            $search = PropertyServices::fetchHandpickedProperties($request->search,$request->type,$request->city,$request->property_type,$price_max,$price_min,$id);
            if(is_array($search))
            return view('site.handpicked-properties');
            else if($search == 0)
                return $this->sendError('Property not found',[],206);
            else if($search == null)
                return $this->sendError('Property not found. Due to Exception in Service',[],500);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            Log::error('Exception encountered. PropertyController->searchProperties Exception: '.$e);
            return $this->sendError('Property not found. Due to Exception.',[],500);
        }
    }
enter code here
```

**This is the code I have used in Service**

```
public function fetchHandpickedProperties($search,$type,$city,$property_type,$price_max,$price_min,$id)
    {
        {
            try
            {
               
                $result = Property::where('project_id','2')
                                    ->select('description','images','id','address','name','currency','price','price_unit','price_per_area','area_per_sq_ft','area_conversions','bedroom','bathroom','created_by','posted_by',\DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%M-%d-%Y") as creation_date'),'carpet_area','verified','construction_status','featured','lat','long')
                                    ->get()->toArray();
                    
                return $result;

            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                Log::error('Exception encountered. PropertyServices->searchProperty Exception: '.$e);
                return $result = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using mysql.  Mysql has a built in sequencing feature named AUTO_INCREMENT.  Why are you not using that?

Comment: So how does that solve my problem ? 

Comment: If project_id was auto_increment, the database would provide a sequence number automatically.  -edit- ok, nevermind.  I see it's a foreign key.

Comment: still not got any solution to my problem

Comment: There are many problems with what you have, and too much information missing from your question.  To start,what is $id?  The simple answer is that you need to pass project_id as a parameter, and use it in fetchHandpickedProperties().

Comment: Yest thank you that is what I need to do but I don't know how to pass project id in fetchhandpickedlroperties().I want that to be dynamic right now I am passing a particular number for eg say project_id=2

Comment: I would be happy If you can tell me how to pass that dynamically

Comment: Add a parameter to `function getProperties(id)` and change the url to `url: '/handpickedproperties/' + id`.  Change query to `$result = Property::where('project_id',$id)`

Comment: Added that but it shows 0 properties whereas when I dd($result) it shows there are properties

Comment: Can someone help in this ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is a bit confusing, it isn't clear exactly what you're trying to do, or what the problem is.  You would make it easier for ppl to help if you tried to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - for eg, there's a lot of Javascript here, which AFAICT is entirely irrelevant to the problem, and just makes it harder for us to see/understand the actual problem.

Comment: However, AFAICT you're asking how to retrieve a single record from the DB, and you already have the ID of that record?  You can replace your entire `fetchHandpickedProperties()` method with a single line: `$property = Property::find($id);`. If you want to do it the Laravel way, you don't even need that line. Change your method signature to: `handpickedProperties(Request $request, Property $property)`, make sure your route looks something like: `Route::post('/handpickedproperties/{$property}', ...`, and Laravel automatically makes `$property` available, assuming the ID matches an actual record.

Comment: I suggest browsing the docs, or trying some intro tutorials if you're just getting started with Laravel.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Sorry, typo - the route I describe above should be without the `$`: `Route::post('/handpickedproperties/{property}', ...`